# how to join a table based on two columns of another

Tags: database, sqlite, organization

I have Table2:

| ZIP | INCOME |
| --- | --- |
| ZTCA5 00619 | 14,601 |
| ZTCA5 12349 | 20,601 |
| ZTCA5 56729 | 20,601 |
| ... | ... |
| ZTCA5 34562 | 20,601 |

Table1:

| ID | ZIP1 | ZIP2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00619 | 006190000 |
| 2 | NULL | 123490000 |
| 3 | 34562 | NULL |

Table2 has many more columns than Table1. The actual Table1 is larger, but I made it 3 rows for the sake of the example.

I want the following result:

| ID | ZIP1 | ZIP2 | ZIP | INCOME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00619 | 006190000 | ZTCA5 00619 | 14,601 |
| 2 | NULL | 123490000 | ZTCA5 12349 | 20,601 |
| 3 | 34562 | NULL | ZTCA5 34562 | 20,601 |

The ZIP2 column is the 9 digit zip code with the first five numbers being the ones I'm interested in.

I tried the following code (with the help of another answer):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t2
LEFT JOIN Table2 t1
ON substr(t1.ZIP, -5)=t2.ZIP1
    OR substr(t1.ZIP,-5)=substr(t2.ZIP2,5)
```

My issue with this code is that it has more rows than my original Table1, which shouldn't happen. The result should have the same amount of rows as Table1. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may join using both `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t1.ZIP1, t1.ZIP2, t2.ZIP, t2.INCOME
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON SUBSTR(t2.ZIP, INSTR(t2.ZIP, ' ') + 1, 5) =
       COALESCE(t1.ZIP1, SUBSTR(t1.ZIP2, 1, 5));
```

Comment: If table 1 has other columns, how can I get the zip/income data to attach to all of table 1? I've played around with it but haven't been able to figure it out. Is it my best bet to just type all the columns of table1 in the select command or is there a more concise way to do it?

Comment: @anni Perhaps `SELECT t1.*` would work for you.  If not, then you would have to explicitly list out all columns you want to select.